# Sequence Labelling with BERT

Tags: pytorch, lstm, huggingface-transformers, torchtext

I am using a model consisting of an embedding layer and an LSTM to perform sequence labelling, in pytorch + torchtext. I have already tokenised the sentences.

If I use self-trained or other pre-trained word embedding vectors, this is straightforward.

But if I use the Huggingface transformers `BertTokenizer.from_pretrained` and `BertModel.from_pretrained` there is a `'[CLS]'` and `'[SEP]'` token added to the beginning and end of the sentence, respectively. So the output of the model becomes a sequence that is two elements longer than the label/target sequence.

What I am unsure of is:

1. Are these two tags needed for the `BertModel` to embed each token of a sentence "correctly"?
2. If they are needed, can I take them out after the BERT embedding layer, before the input to the LSTM, so that the lengths are correct in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, `BertModel` needed them since without those special symbols added, the output representations would be different. However, my experience says, if you fine-tune `BertModel` on the labeling task without `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` token added, then you may not see a significant difference. If you use `BertModel` to extract **fixed** word features, then you better add those special symbols.
2. Yes, you can take out the embedding of those special symbols. In fact, this is a general idea for sequence labeling or tagging tasks.

I suggest taking a look at some sequence labeling or tagging examples using BERT to become confident about your modeling decisions. You can find NER tagging example using Huggingface transformers [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch/token-classification).