# Sequence to sequence classification (predicting sequence of labels) using Transformers

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, text-classification, sentence-transformers

Im looking for a way to feed a transformer (HuggingFace trained model) a sequence of sentences(introducing context) in order to predict a sequence of labels. The goal is to predict each sentence by itself when considering the context of the complete text.
Already used sliding window to concatenate the sentences but this is less a sequence to sequence as I need it to be

Tried to look for open source code for the matter of SSC for sentences, found an implementation to LSTM (looking for an advanced deep learning model)
Concatenating sentences for context - performance issues (looking for an advanced and faster way)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequence Labelling with BERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717097/sequence-labelling-with-bert)

Comment: Which model are you using? Does it use a classification token or something like that?

Comment: Sequence Labelling with BERT  : no, Im looking for a solution transformers based
Im using transformers- distilbert and roberta for now